# Android Studio how can I Do different task for single and double back button press

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onbackpressed

There are a lot of answers on "Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity" and similar things but what I am trying to do with my project is that I want to do different things for single and double click of back button
For example in my case I want to go to Home screen / Main activity of my app if the back button is pressed once and simultaneously show a toast " Press Back Again To Exit " and if the user do that the app does just that . 
I am really struggling to write a code for this
I have tried this but it doesn't work as intended , with this even on double press the app doesnt exit .
Any help is appreciated .
My code

```
enter code here
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private long mBackPressed;
 public void onBackPressed() {
 if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis())
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }


            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
 mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, however its because you are setting `mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();` every time the back button is pressed, so it will never pass the first if statement you have. It seems also as if you want to track how many times they've clicked the back button.

Try this,

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
private long mBackPressed = -1;
private int clicks = 0;

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBackPressed == -1) //checks if the time hasnt been set yet
        mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    clicks++; //or you can put this in the if statement below
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mBackPressed = -1; //resets the time the click was made
        clicks = 0; //resets the clicks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method might be a simple solution :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     private final static int TIME_INTERVAL = 500;
     long backPressed = 0L;

     if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - backPressed < TIME_INTERVAL))
            System.exit(0); // do what you want on double click
     else {
            backPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            getSnackbar(R.string.double_back_press_message,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onBackPressed();
      }
}
```